# Specific query in mongo

Tags: mongodb

i have this collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f3176d21a8b87fcf14658a6"),
  "quiosco_id" : "11111111        ",
  "transacciones" : [{
      "transaccion_uuid" : "60be5247-6a38-4da2-b7b3-ea1dfaf0293b",
      "machine_uuid" : "11111111        ",
      "audit" : "146018",
      "mti" : "1810",
      "direction" : "1",
      "monto" : 1.1499999761581421,
      "fecha" : "07/02/2012 02:39:14 PM",
      "data1" : "181052200000028000001111111111111000000000115"
    }, {
      "transaccion_uuid" : "adcbda16-dda7-4887-9295-2e47df7520e2",
      "machine_uuid" : "11111111        ",
      "audit" : "146018",
      "mti" : "1810",
      "direction" : "2",
      "monto" : 1.1499999761581421,
      "fecha" : "07/02/2012 02:39:14 PM",
      "data1" : "181052200000008000001111111111111000000000115"
    }
}
```

I need only one document with a specific transaccion_uuid.

Answer (score 2):

Any mongodb query always return root document, so you can't load only embedded document. 
If you need root document that contains transaction with specific id you can do it easy via [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation):

```
db.items.find({"transacciones.transaccion_uuid": 
                                              "adcbda16-dda7-4887-9295-2e47df7520e2"})
```

If you need just one transaction from embedded document you need find it from within your driver code manually.

Comment: thnaks for your answer, i try everything, but the solution is what you say.

Comment: @user1226237 Please accept an answer if it helped you. That's the way to say thank you on stackoverflow.